# Access classes of one project from another in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a separate spring project called `UserService` and an another project `TransactionService`. I want to access `UserService` project's `UserPrincipal` class.

```java
public PagedResponse<TransactionResponse> getAllTransactions(@CurrentUser UserPrincipal currentUser,
                                                                     @RequestParam(value="page") int page,
                                                                     @RequestParam(value = "size") int size) {
            return transactionService.getAllTransactions(currentUser, page, size);
        }
```

Also I added the Maven dependency to the pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.assignment</groupId>
    <artifactId>user-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

But still cannot import the `UserService`'s `UserPrincipal` class.
Please suggest me a way to do this.

Comment: What error do you get? Have you installed `user-service` to your local repo (by running `mvn clean install`)?

Comment: I am getting an error saying Cannot resolve symbol "UserPrincipal". Then I added the Maven dependency. But it is still getting the same error. 
Yes I have installed the service to local repository

Comment: Probably refreshing your project should fix it depending on the IDE you are using. Also, you can expand the `user-service` jar under maven dependencies and check if it contains 'UserPrincipal' (again depends on IDE).

Answer (score 0):

I know that question is 2 years ago, but maybe will help to someone.

This particular example is for gradle, but I assume that is not very different for maven.

You need to put in your build file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenLocal() // it's very important that mavenLocal() is before mavenCentral
    mavenCentral()
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'org.example'
            artifactId = 'some-name'
            version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

            pom {
                name = 'Some name'
                description = 'A description of my library'
            }

            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```